# After select the Column of row ,Grid is moving to the left side in EditorGridPanel of GWTEXT

Tags: java, gwt, grid, gwt-ext

I created a Grid using EditorGridPanel with CheckBoxSelectionModel in gwtext.Now I am disabling the check box after select the Column of row using the below code:

```
cbSelectionModel.addListener(new RowSelectionListener() {

                public boolean doBeforeRowSelect(RowSelectionModel c, int rowIndex,
                        boolean keepExisting, Record record) {

                    if (!keepExisting) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;

                }

                public void onRowDeselect(RowSelectionModel sm, int rowIndex,
                        Record record) {

                }

                public void onRowSelect(RowSelectionModel sm, int rowIndex,
                        Record record) {

                }

                public void onSelectionChange(RowSelectionModel sm) {

                }

            }

            );
```

Now the problem is If I click the column which is far away from the checkbox in the Grid.Then the grid is moving to left side everytime.Please suggest me how to reslove this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using the below line:

```
checkInViolationGrid.getGrid().getView().setAutoFill(true);
```